# Need help identifying SOD-123 packaged Zener diode with WG G0 marking

Tags: diodes, identification, zener

I'm looking for help identifying a SOD-123 packaged Zener diode with WG G0 marking like the one in the photo.  The board has quite a few of these with one of them completely burnt.  The closest I've come across is a BZT52C11, but it doesn't quite have the same markings.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: photo of unknown zener diode on a PCB]

Comment: Spend some time figuring out their *role*.

Comment: If you have quite a few of them, couldn't you just find a working one, pull it off the board, and measure its zener voltage?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like BZT52C11 from Diodes incorporated. The "GO" part is datecode, so it can be different. Look at this datasheet: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds18004.pdf (page 1 - "Marking information").

Answer (score 0):

BZT52C10 or 11 seems correct, from several manufacturers: 
https://smd.yooneed.one/code5747.html 
https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/wg